# Redux-saga call effect access to status code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

While playing with redux-saga ive noticed that call effect when error occurs pass to catch clause just a text of the error. How can i access response status code? for example i catch if status code is 401 i want to implement some logic there.

For example:

```
try {
    const response = yield call(fetch, uri, options);
    //some more logic to dispatch eventual success response
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    //here is only printed ie 'Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch' but i need to access as well status code here
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is happening when you get a 401? `TypeError` is a strange error for that.

Comment: Hmm, im not sure tbh, maybe you are right, maybe request is not even firing because of possible cors issue.